'dict object' has no attribute 'test_name'. This can happen when calling a macro that does not exist. Check for typos and install package dependencies
I'm calling a test within a model column in my schema.yml file, however, when running a "dbt compile" it says it doesn't find the test in the macros folder, and I configured that the tests should be looked for in the tests folder inside the dbt project
This is the test code, and it is inside a package named common_dbt_functions
{% test mais_recente_true(model, column_name) %}

with cte_mais_recente as (
  SELECT *
  FROM {{ model }} as fv
  WHERE fv.mais_recente = False
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM {{ model }} as fv2
    WHERE fv.{{ column_name }} = fv2.{{ column_name }}
    AND fv2.mais_recente = true
  )
)

SELECT *
FROM cte_mais_recente

{% endtest %}

This is where I call the test
version: 2

models:
  - name: fato_solucoes_financeiras
    tags: ["vendas", "consorcio"]
    columns: 
      - name: id_documento
        tests:
          - not_null:
              tags: ["generic", "null"]
          - common_dbt_functions.mais_recente_true:
              tags: ["unique", "mais_recente_true"]

But if I change the test, which is in the tests folder, and put the dbt compile in the macros folder, it stops showing this error
I tried looking for problems similar to this, but the most I found were instructions for configuring the tests directory in dbt-project
